# Change Score or Regressor Variable Method - Should I regress $Y_1$ over $X$ and $Y_0$ or $(Y_1-Y_0)$ over $X$

Tags: least-squares, panel-data, pre-post-comparison

I have data about investment preferences 1 year before the Covid and during the Covid lockdown.

Some changes appear using simple T-Test. I want to be able to assess if these changes are particularly strong for some specific demographics (e.g., older individuals ($X_1$), individuals with lower income ($X_2$), etc...).

Should I use the initial level of my dependant variable in the regressions? Basically, if I want to use OLS regressions to investigate which independant variable correlate with the change in my dependant variable, which model is preferrable?

Model 1 (apparently called Change Score Method):
$(Y_2-Y_1)= \beta_1 . X_1+ \beta_2 . X_2 $

Model 2 (apparently called Regressor Variable Method) Score Method):
$Y_2= \beta_1 . X_1+ \beta_2 . X_2 + \beta_3 . Y_1 $

Thank you so much for your help - Any reference would also be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a dup:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods have been used. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_analysis) for example. It depends what question you want to answer. If you want to talk mostly about "change" you can use

```
(Y2-Y1) ~ X1 + X2            # (1)
```

Basal (Y1) should not be added to above equation as it will always be correlated with difference (Y2-Y1) - see comments below by @EdM and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476176/difference-between-repeated-measures-anova-ancova-and-linear-mixed-effects-mode).

On the other hand, if you want to discuss factors affecting "final value", you can use

```
Y2 ~ X1 + X2 + Y1            # (2)
```

However, since repeated measurements (Y1,Y2 at 2 times) have been done on same subject, hence mixed model is also often used. (including interactions as commented by @dbwilson below):

```
Y ~ X1 + X2 + time + X1*time + X2*time + (1|subject)
```

Following simplified version of formula is effectively same as above:

```
Y ~ X1*time + X2*time + (1|subject)            # (3)
```

There is another method commonly used, especially in biomedical literature: **"Percent change"**, i.e.

```
(100*(Y2-Y1)/Y1) ~ X1 + X2            # (4)
```

It is not correct to keep Y1 as a predictor variable in this last method as there will be strong correlation between baseline and percent change.

I think this last method (percent change) is most understandable.

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476176/difference-between-repeated-measures-anova-ancova-and-linear-mixed-effects-mode) for more information on this topic.

***Edit:***
For equation 3, data should be in form such that columns are: subject, x1, x2, time and y. Hence, y1 and y2 will be in 2 different rows (having same subject, x1 and x2 but different y value and time). For other equations, data will be in form such that columns are: subject, x1, x2, y1, y2 (one row for each subject; subject column will be ignored here).

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. In the end, given that I was mostly interested in change, I used (Y2-Y1) ~ X1 + X2             It is however interesting to see the last two methods you propose. Thank you again!

Comment: Regressing the difference against the initial value is not a good idea. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/476445/28500) and its links and [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/476453/28500) to the question ["What are the worst (commonly adopted) ideas/principles in statistics?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/476424/28500)

Comment: I have added a note regarding this in answer above.

Comment: In the mixed-model, the interaction between X1*time and X2*time are estimating the same effect as the X1 and X2 effects in the change score model. The code, however, should be Y~X1+X2+time+X1*time+X2*time + (1|subject).

Comment: I have added this in answer above with your reference.

Comment: I don't understand why Equation 3 is correct here. Does Y equal Y2? I assume the variable Time is a centered dummy code (e.g., -1, 1), so where does the base rate get controlled for? I can't figure out where Y1 is in this model.

Comment: I have added clarification on this in my answer above.